# Undefined Method (NoMethodError) ruby and Gosu

Tags: ruby, libgosu

I'm having a problem calling the x position and y position of a Player. When I call the origin_object.x and origin_object.y with the class Projectile it gives me this error:

```
asteroids.rb:35:in `update': undefined method `x' for #<Player:0x007fa7c307c520> (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/gosu-0.10.4/lib/gosu/patches.rb:135:in `tick'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/gosu-0.10.4/lib/gosu/patches.rb:135:in `tick'
    from asteroids.rb:68:in `<main>'
```

This is my code:

```
class Player

  attr_accessor :x, :y, :angle, :lives, :score
  def initialize
    @image = Gosu::Image.new("assets/nave1.png")
    @x = @y = @vel_x = @vel_y = @angle = 0.0
    @score = 0 #Puntaje
    @lives = 5 #Vida
  end
end
```

this is the projectile file

```
class Projectile
  attr_reader :x, :y, :angle
  def initialize(origin_object)
    @alive = true
    @x, @y = origin_object.x, origin_object.y
    @angle = origin_object.angle
    @speed_modifier = 7
    @image = Gosu::Image.new('assets/projectile.png')
    @distance_traveled, @max_distance = 0, 50
  end
end
```

this is the main file (which I use to run the project)

```
require 'gosu'
require './lib/Player.rb'
require './lib/Projectile.rb'

class GameWindow < Gosu::Window

  def initialize
    super(1000, 700, false) #Creacion Pantalla
    self.caption = "Asteroids Redes" #Titulo Pantalla
    @font = Gosu::Font.new(self, "assets/victor-pixel.ttf", 34)
  end

  def setup_game
    @player = Player.new
    @player.warp(650, 350)
    @game_in_progress = true
    @projectiles = []
  end

  #--------------------------------------#
  def update

    if Gosu::button_down? Gosu::KbQ #Salir con tecla Q
      close
    end
    if button_down? Gosu:: KbP
      setup_game unless @game_in_progress
    end

    if @player #si existe jugador permite moverlo
      if Gosu::button_down? Gosu::KbSpace
        p @player.x
        #@projectiles << Projectile.new(p @player)
      end
      if Gosu::button_down? Gosu::KbLeft or Gosu::button_down? Gosu::GpLeft then
        @player.turn_left
      end
      if Gosu::button_down? Gosu::KbRight or Gosu::button_down? Gosu::GpRight then
        @player.turn_right
      end
      if Gosu::button_down? Gosu::KbUp or Gosu::button_down? Gosu::GpButton0 then
        @player.accelerate
      end
      @player.move
      @projectiles.each {|projectile| projectile.move}
    end

  end
  #--------------------------------------#
  def draw
    unless @game_in_progress #Si el no se esta ejecutando muestra el menu
      @font.draw("ASTEROIDS", 260, 220, 50, 3, 3, Gosu::Color::rgb(255, 255, 255))
      @font.draw("Presiona 'p' Para Jugar", 300, 320, 50, 1, 1, Gosu::Color::rgb(13, 123, 255))
      @font.draw("Presiona 'q' Para Salir", 305, 345, 50, 1, 1, Gosu::Color::rgb(13, 123, 255))
    end
    if @player #Si existe jugador lo dibuja
      @player.draw
      @projectiles.each {|projectile| projectile.draw}
    end
  end
  #--------------------------------------#
end
#........................................#
window = GameWindow.new
window.show
```

Answer (score 0):

I have copied the code from your three files, added empty method stubs for `move`, `draw`, `accelerate`, `turn_left`/`turn_right` so that the code will not immediately crash.

When I start the game and press P, then space, I see "0.0" in the terminal as the result of `p @player.x`.

Are you maybe running another version of the code than what you have included in your question?